# Using jQuery to gather dynamically added dom elements after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dynamically-generated

Alright so I recently received this project from a client. They needed a offline and online website that could be loaded via usb drive onto ipads or remote sources with no internet connection. So all of the files had to be ".html" extension. In order to make maintenance and changes easier I used javascript to load global portions of content into the pages, specifically the nav. I am having trouble trying to find the new elements I've added, here is a sample of the nav.tpl I'm loading via ajax into the dom:

```
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="nav-grey"><span class="spacer"></span>HOME<span class="spacer"></span></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="unmatched_simplicity.html" class="nav-red">unmatched <br/> SIMPLICITY</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="unmatched_simplicity-easy_to_use.html">Easy to Use</a></li>
                            <li><a href="unmatched_simplicity-cashier_workstation.html">Cashier Workstation Screen</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="unmatched_simplicity-fuel.html">Fuel</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="unmatched_simplicity-fuel-authorize_pump.html">Authorize Pump</a></li>
                                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="unmatched_simplicity-fuel-all_stop.html">All Stop</a></li>
```

Here is the javascript:

$.get( "lib/nav.tpl", function( navItems ) {
    $( ".nav" ).html( navItems );
});

Now I have a naming convention I am using for organizational purposes as well as bread crumbs and now I am trying to use it to detect the nav item that the current page is on. Basically each level of pages is separated by "-". My goal was to use the url to find the anchor with href = to the current page, then go to its parent "li" and add the active class ".active". This is what I have:

```
( function( window ) {

        var location = locationTiers = '';

        location = window.location.pathname;
        location = location.substr( location.indexOf('/') + 1 ); 
        location = location.replace('.html', '');

        locationTiers = location.split('-');

console.log( $( 'a[href="'+ locationTiers[0] +'.html"]' ).parent('li') );

    }) ( window );
```

It's strange because I can find the anchor if I remove ".parent('li')", but with the ".parent('li')" it returns empty. It seems like if it couldn't find the "li" it wouldn't be able to find the "a". I know about the .on() subsitute for live but this is mostly for detecting events.

I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
$('body','a[href="'+ locationTiers[0] +'.html"]').parent('li')
```

Similar to .on live method but this doesn't work either. If anyone can help me figure out how I can find this dynamically added item it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: the problem could be that the location code is getting executed before the navigation items are loaded into the page

Comment: can you change the console to `console.log( $( 'a[href="'+ locationTiers[0] +'.html"]' ).parent().get() );` and see what element is returned

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm pretty sure that's happening, I'm just not sure what to load events after certain actions have fired.

Comment: @ArunPJohny That returns an empty array

Comment: yes just place your code inside the callback of `$.get( "lib/nav.tpl", function( navItems ) { $( ".nav" ).html( navItems ); });`

Comment: checkout my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the navigation items are loaded by the ajax request, you need move your location code to the success handler of the load nav items

```
$.get("lib/nav.tpl", function (navItems) {
    $(".nav").html(navItems);

    var location = locationTiers = '';

    location = window.location.pathname;
    location = location.substr(location.indexOf('/') + 1);
    location = location.replace('.html', '');

    locationTiers = location.split('-');

    console.log($('a[href="' + locationTiers[0] + '.html"]').parent('li'));

});
```

Comment: Perfect that worked, funny, right after you said that I thought check docs on $.get and found it has a .done() function which is what I used. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @TomBird both the `done()` and the success callback which I used here does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
( function( window ) {

    var location = locationTiers = '';

    location = window.location.pathname;
    location = location.substr( location.indexOf('/') + 1 ); 
    location = location.replace('.html', '');

    locationTiers = location.split('-');
    var subject = $('a[href="'+ locationTiers[0] +'.html"]');
    var parent = subject.parent();
    console.log({'is_li':parent.is('li'),'parent':parent});

}) ( window );
```

It should return an object that has "is_li" of true or false, and if it is true, then the second part, should have a jQuery li object.

There's a reason the following doesn't work:

```
$('body','a[href="'+ locationTiers[0] +'.html"]').parent('li');
```

jQuery's second argument on a selector $('body', '{this guy}') is actually where you can feed it an XML/HTML string/object and search for "body" (or whatever your selector is) inside of it.

You should provide some more information, what is the purpose of looking up the LI's to mark them active when clicked? Or is it just for when content is pulled in or are you wanting to select a default menu item?

Regardless this should be a fairly easy fix.  Keep us posted.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer @Destreyf , unfortunately that did not return the li, the client just wants an active state added to the current page anchor so that the user knows where they came from

Comment: Can you modify the console.log to be the following? console.log(locationTiers,subject,parent); and tell me what happens

Comment: The question got solved I just need to place the code call into a function that was called from with the done / success method. Thanks!